# Why am I not getting the right return message?

Tags: java

Below I have a snippet of code that I won't work. I get input in my main method then pass that input into another method to check for validation. But it doesn't really check correctly. If I input `99` for `month` and `day` I expect it to give me the message `Check Month`.

Instead I get:
   `THIS
    THIS`

If I input `02` for month and `99` for day, I expect it to give me the message: `Check day`.  Instead I get `THIS THIS`

If I input `02` for both, I expect it to run and continue running other methods. Instead I get `THIS THIS`.

```
public class Date {

private Calendar parsedDate;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Date main = new Date();
        System.out.println("Enter a date (use the format -> (MM/DD/YYYY)");

    //declare Scanner
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a month (MM): ");
    String month = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a day (DD): ");
    String day = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter a year (YYYY): ");
    String year = in.nextLine();

    if (main.isValidDate(month, day, year) == true) 
    {
        main.newFormat(month, day, year);
        main.isLeapYear(year);
        main.dayNumber(month, day);
    }
    else if (main.isValidDate(month, day, year) == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
}//end of main

private boolean isValidDate(String month, String day, String year) 
{
    //check month       
    if(month == "01" || month == "03" || month == "04" ||
       month == "05" || month == "06" || month == "07" || month == "08" ||
       month == "09" || month == "10" || month == "11" || month == "12")
    { 
        //check day
        if(day == "01" || day == "02" || day == "03" || day == "04" ||
           day == "05" || day == "06" || day == "07" || day == "08" ||
           day == "09" || day == "10" || day == "11" || day == "12" ||
           day == "13" || day == "14" || day == "15" || day == "16" ||
           day == "17" || day == "18" || day == "19" || day == "20" ||
           day == "21" || day == "22" || day == "23" || day == "24" ||
           day == "25" || day == "26" || day == "27" || day == "28" ||
           day == "29" || day == "30" || day == "31")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Check Day");
            return false;
        }
    }//end of check month
    else if (month == "02")
    {
        if (day == "28" || day == "29")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }//end of month 2
    else
    {
        System.out.println("THIS");
        return false;
    }

    parsedDate = null;// if it's valid set the parsed Calendar object up.
    return true;
}//end of isValidDate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the answers explaining the reason it's *currently* not working - using `==` rather than `equals` - I would suggest you *don't* just start using `equals`.

Instead, parse the user input into numbers first, and then validate those... it's much easier to perform numeric comparisons with *numbers* rather than strings. Something like:

```
private boolean isValidDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    // Adjust for whatever bounds you want
    if (year < 1900 || year > 2100) {
        System.out.println("Check year");
        return false;
    }

    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        System.out.println("Check month");
        return false;
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
    if (day < 1 || day > calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
        System.out.println("Check day");
        return false;
    }
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    // Store calendar somewhere if you want...
    return true;
}
```

Additionally, I'd strongly recommend the use of [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as a much nicer date/time API if you can.

EDIT: Your next problem seems to be this block:

```
if (main.isValidDate(month, day, year) == true) 
{
    main.newFormat(month, day, year);
    main.isLeapYear(year);
    main.dayNumber(month, day);
}
else if (main.isValidDate(month, day, year) == false)
{
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
}
```

Now the code I've presented already checks everything *and* constructs a `Calendar` - it's not clear what the methods in the `if` block are meant to do. But you don't need to call `isValidDate` a second time. You just need:

```
// Assuming you're using my new method...
if (isValidDate(year, month, day)) {
    // Do whatever you need to do
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input");
}
```

Comment: As Jon wrote you should declare constants and compare in this way `if (month==JANUARY)` etc. It's more clearly.

Comment: If I put in the wrong month, it prints out `"Check Month"` twice! Why is this?

Comment: @DwellingPlace: Well currently you're calling `isValidDate` twice. Don't do that.

Comment: Not sure what I should do to not do that... Any help? ;x

Comment: @PatrykRoszczyniała: Where did I write anything about declaring a constant? `Calendar` already defines those constants, but I wouldn't want to check against each of them anyway...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks! I see it now! :)
If I were to reprompt for input, how would I do that?

Comment: @Jon, I've added my comment just before you've pasted the code.

Comment: @PatrykRoszczyniała: Sure, but I *never* suggested declaring constants, so it's not clear where your comment came from at all...

Comment: @DwellingPlace: Well, you'd need a loop... but I'm not going to rewrite every bit of your code for you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I figured it out. I used a `while` after each requested entry and made additional methods to validate them. :)

Answer (score 5):

You should use the equals method for comparing Strings. When using the `==` operator, you compare the Strings' addresses, and not their content.

Comment: o. derp. >.<
Thanks, I completely forgot!

Answer (score 4):

This `month == "01"` is not the correct way to compare `String`s in Java.

You are trying to compare memory locations of the two variables, which aren't likely to be equal.

Instead you should be using `month.equals("01")`.

Comment: Can I use the || inside of that?
ie `month.equals("01" || "02" || 03)` ?

Comment: @DwellingPlace No.  In fact JonSkeet gave you an exellent suggestion.  If you can parse the values to an `int` value first, then you can compare ranges `if (month >= 1 && month <= 3){...}`

Answer (score 2):

There are two big mistakes

1. you are comparing string with equals equals which will compare memory not content so 
   the line  `if(month == "01")` should be `if("01".equals(month))`
2. The condition for checking valid date `if (main.isValidDate(month, day, year) == true)` should be like  `if (main.isValidDate(month, day, year))`

Answer (score 1):

It would be MUCH more efficient and easier to read/write/test to convert your string to integer and then check that (e.g.use `int monthVal = Integer.parseInt(month);` thenyou can check if (a) it parsed properly,with a try/catch around it and (b) test the value with `if (monthVal > 0 && monthVal< 13) { /* month is good */}`

Comment: I see!
Can I still return the same way?

Comment: yes of course you can :)

Comment: Good luck. pls come back and accept one of the answers when you have it working :)